# Using "pluck" -> undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried using pluck as a shortcut to select one or more attributes without loading a bunch of records just to grab the attributes I want. Which is pretty much 1:1 the intended use (see here: [Pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)).

There are 2 tables: "demands" and "parents".

the idea is to create a new entry in the table "demands". The table "demands" contains a column "parent_id" and the demand/parent models are properly associated through belongs_to and has_many.

this is my code using the pluck method:

```
    <%= form.label :parent_id %><br>
    <% if can? :optimize, Matching %> <----TEST FOR ADMIN RIGHTS
        <%= form.collection_select :parent_id, Parent.all, :id, :fullname %>
    <% else %>
        <%= @parent.pluck(:name) %> <-----ERROR ERROR ERROR
        <%= form.hidden_field :parent_id, value: @parent.pluck(:id) %>
    <% end %><br><br>
```

The corresponding datatable "parents" obviously contains all three of these values, firstname, name and id.

However, this is my error:

```
undefined method `pluck' for nil:NilClass
```

error occurs in /app/views/demands/_form.html.erb

update: this is the complete _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for Demand.new do |form| %> 

    <%= form.label :parent_id %><br>
    <% if can? :optimize, Matching %>
        <%= form.collection_select :parent_id, Parent.all, :id, :fullname %>
    <% else %>
        <%= @parent.pluck(:name) %>
        <%= form.hidden_field :parent_id, value: @parent.pluck(:id) %>
    <% end %><br><br>

    <%= form.label :demand %><br>
    <%= form.number_field :demand %>

    <%= form.label :shift_id %><br>
    <%= form.collection_select :shift_id, Shift.all, :id, :description %>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= form.submit 'Post a new job', {:class => "btn btn-primary"} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the demand controller action "create"

```
def new
@demands = Demand.new
if cannot? :optimize, Matching
  @parent = Parent.where(parents: {firstname: current_user.firstname, name: current_user.name})
end
end    

def create
@demand = Demand.new(demand_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @demand.save
    format.html { redirect_to @demand, notice: 'Demand was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @demand }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @demand.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Your @parent instance var is nil. Show us more code, especially action in the controller and the view including the partial

Comment: @Fred updated the original question, is that all you wanted to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@parent` instance var is only defined in the create action. So, if `@demand.save` returns false (Invalid object), the exception occurs because @parent is nil

Comment: edit: solved it. I was missing a param in the privat section of my controlle... simple typo as always!